# Let custom URL fall back to search in Play Store

Tags: android

Imagine you have a custom URL handler registered in your Android app. Some other app / webpage contains a link with an URL that would be recognized by this handler, but unfortunately the app is not yet installed on the user's device. Does the developer of the app has any options to hint Google's Play Store to find your app in the Play Store by searching for this URL scheme and installing this particular app or is the user basically lost with the "no activity found to handle this intent" problem?

Comment: How about you just let them put the link to the Google Play Store in their website, and recognize that URL in your app with your URL handler? Like that it will always go to the Play Store, but - once installed - also to your app.

Comment: Hrm... thats the question, aren't all market://-style URLs automatically catched for Play Store? If yes, then wouldn't the user receive this popup "with what action do you want to open this" every time when he clicks on such a link, even if the app is long installed?  Doesn't this look a bit awkward?

Comment: Well yeah, it would be an extra and maybe a bit weird step, but its the closest you can get to what you want. As your app isn't installed yet, you have no control over what that mobile does with the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`PackageManager.resolveActivity()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#resolveActivity%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) to check if that particular app is installed:

```
Uri customUri = Uri.parse("mycustomhandler://my.custom.encoded.URI");
Intent customIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, customUri);

if (getPackageManager().resolveActivity(customIntent, 0) == null) {
    // The package is not installed,
    // implement your logic here
}
```

Comment: Well, in principle, you should not be worried about how and why other developers' applications are failing...

Comment: In principle no, but the thing is that a sharing functionality should be implemented and multiple sources (twitter, fb, google+) should link on a specific resource that opens up in the app. This works all fine with a regular IntentFilter if the app is installed, but not at all if the app is not installed. I guess my options are very limited here...